# How does electrical devices consume power?

Tags: voltage, watts, electric-machine

I'm curious to know how does an electrical device can consume any amount of power it is required? Suppose the voltage here is 220V. How can you get any amount of electrical power say. 1000 watts out of it? Please tell me what I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The power line may be supplying a fixed voltage, like 220V, but how much *current* the device draws is up to the device.  Power is voltage times current, so you can see how the device determines the power by determining the current.

For exmaple, in order to take 1 kW from a 220V line, a device would have to draw 1kW / 220V = 4.5A.  If this were purely a resistor, it would be 220V / 4.5A = 48Ω.  A 24 Ω resistor would take twice that power (2 kW), and a 96 Ω resistor half that (500 W).  All these can be connected at the same time to the same 220 V line and each will still take the power calculated above.

At some upper limit, the 220 V line can't supply more current.  At that point something has to give, like the voltage sag.  In houses, a fuse will blow or a breaker pop before there is any significant sag.

Comment: Something has to give... In fact this happens every summer in many places as lots of AC units are running.

Answer (score 2):

It's a quite general question, that can have many answers, and also can be intended in many ways.

The power is the amount of energy consumed/supplied (in fact it's an abstraction because the energy is conserved for the physical principle - but focus on the electric side) over a time unit (second). In electricity, this happens to be V(t)*I(t), and the reason comes from Ohm's law for the electric field.

But the point is that this power, when absorbed by a device, does not always do that for the same principle, as the device can use it for many tasks: think to a motor, or a lightbulb. So you have always a part of the power (can be all or a negligible part) that goes into heat (see Joule's effect) and the rest depends from the device.

But if you want a direct answer to how to get the amount, as I said it's V*I, and to get I from V you have to know Z that is the impedance of the device, and is defined by V(t)/I(t).

Note that these values are time dependent, as the device can (and often does) change its characteristics with time.

The impedance, as the formula says, defines the amount of current that the device absorbs given that it's supplied with a certain voltage.

I'll save you the part about alternate voltage because it's going to complicate things too much.

Answer (score 0):

A device's resistance to a voltage determines what current it allows to pass through it. So if the device is allowing 4.5 Amps at 220 V to pass throught it, then it is consuming 1kW. The resistance that the device gives at that voltage would be (whatever) Ωs. Note resistors are rated typically at 1/4 watt or 1/2 watt. That rating is the amount of power it can dissapate as heat (resistance generates heat). 1kW of dissapation through a 1/4 watt resistor will cause a fire, as the resistor cannot dissapate that much heat.